# UITextField -- observe changes to selectedTextRange?

Tags: ios, text, uitextfield, selection

Is there any way to observe changes to the selectedTextRange of a UITextField?

I tried observing all UIControlEvents.  But changing the selectedTextRange does not trigger a UIControlEvent.

Another dead end -- UIKit classes are not KVO compliant.

Then there is the UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification.  But that's for changes to the text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Subclass `UITextField` as follows.

```
@interface WJTextField : UITextField
@end

@protocol WJTextFieldDelegate <UITextFieldDelegate>
- (void) textFieldDidChangeSelection: (UITextField *) textField;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation WJTextField

- (void) setSelectedTextRange: (UITextRange *) selectedTextRange
{
    [super setSelectedTextRange: selectedTextRange];
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(textFieldDidChangeSelection:)])
        [(id <WJTextFieldDelegate>) self.delegate textFieldDidChangeSelection: self];
}

@end
```

Then add `-textFieldDidChangeSelection:` to your text field's delegate.

**Caveat:** This delegate message will be sent only when the cursor is moved, it will *not* be sent when typing or pasting text, for those events you have to implement `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`, where the selection range is going to either be set to `range.location + [string length]` (if you return `YES`) or remain the same (if you return `NO`).

Comment: I just want to mention, that this does indeed fire when typing or pasting text. At least in iOS8, I didn't check anything else.